# Do newer GFCI receptacles still trip due to inductive load from motors?

Tags: gfci

I am rewiring a kitchen and faced with a dilemma of having the garbage disposal on a GFCI circuit.

Will it trip when turned off like the older GFCI's?

Comment: If you'll accept anecdotal evidence, my garbage disposal is on an GFCI and it has never tripped in the past 2 years that I've lived here. I'm curious whether he NEC would require a GFCI for a garbage disposal plugged into an outlet below the sink -- the outlet is within 6 ft of the sink, but it's not a countertop outlet.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer:
Unless your disposal leaks current via ground or via the water/sewer line, you won't have any problems.

More details:
GFCI is really great for appliances that interface with water during the cource of their normal duties. Sumps, washers, disposals, sprinkler systems.  As they degrade, they are especially able to cause dangerous leakage current that can hurt people nearby.

I hate answers that make decisions for the asker.  But this is one of the cases where its really pretty clear.  Even if it was a nuisance, it would be worth it.

If you want an EASY way to gain confidence that it won't be a nuisance, wire the outlet to an old computer power cord for a few days and run the disposal a few times to see if it ever trips.  If it does you should check resistance between hot and ground, neutral and ground, hot and your sink, and neutral and your sink.  They ought to all be infinite resistance.  If not, then you have a significant safety problem with your disposal.

Answer (score 1):

If you hard-wire the thing, then no GFCI required.

Answer (score 1):

This thread has aged but the question is ever new so...

With 2022 on the horizon at this post, I just bought several new GFCI outlets (15A "S... E..." brand) to update as needed.

All units false-trip erratically (once every few or many cycles) when load is inductive and relay contacts break or on cord unplug. None are tripped at any other time.

The inductive load can be as small as a 7-watt aquarium pump or the tiny transformer inside an LED bulb, up to a fractional horsepower induction motor (shaded pole or PSC).

Even with aggressive arc suppression across relay contacts, the surge-on-break still sometimes triggers the false GFCI trip. This can of course be unbelievably annoying.

To check if the manufacturer's design or build quality was at fault, I did try another brand. Same result.

So my current answer would have to be: "Yes, it will trip."

If there are any brands that tend to *not* false trip and it's not a rule violation to name them, suggestions are welcome.